# What happens if a solid impacts another solid above its speed of sound?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I would like to know what happens if a solid object (e.g. steel ball) would hit another solid object (e.g. thick steel wall) with a speed higher than the speed of sound in the solids material. I read about [Hypervelocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervelocity) in Wikipedia. This article mentions speed of over 2500m/s which are leading to temporary liquefaction and creation of plasma discharges. However, 2500m/s are still below the speed of sound of more than 5100m/s for steel. Is there a difference if the actual speed of sound is exceeded? (Or is the speed of sound of the solid decreased during the impact?)

Are there any equivalences to a gas such as a sound barrier and shock waves and some kind of Mach cone?

And if the impactor has an elongated shape, is there any influence on the end of the impactor while the front is crashing into the steel plate? (this is related to the question about the shock wave)

Best regards

Comment: It will depend on the material. You can also consider the kinetic energy of an atom in the material compared to the typical chemical bond energy of a few electron volts. At speeds of a few thousand m/s the kinetic energy will exceed the chemical bond energy.

Comment: Thank you for the information/the idea to compare the kinetic energy with the chemical bond energy. If the question is better to answer for a specific material, we could select steel as the material of interest..